# Finding the inverse and power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, inverse

So I was given this question Let A = $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      -1&2\\
      1&3
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Find a) $A^{-1}$, b)$A^{3}$, c) $(A^{-1})^3$, and finally d) use answers to (b) and (c) to show that $(A^{-1})^3$ is the inverse of $A^3$

So here is my take on it.

So for part a) i did,

$A^{-1}$ = $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      d/(ad-bc)&-b/(ad-bc)\\
      -c/(ad-bc)&a/(ad-bc)
    \end{array}
\right] $$

= $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      3/((-1*3)-(2*1))&-2/((-1*3)(2*1)\\
      -1/((-1*3)-(2*1))&-1/((-1*3)-(2*1)
    \end{array}
\right] $$

= $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      2/-5&-2/-5\\
      -1/-5&-1/-5
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I'm pretty sure I'm correct but I'm completely confused about the rest and how to go about it.

Comment: $A^3 = AAA$.  Just do the multiplication.  Likewise for $(A^{-1})^3$.  Then to show that $(A^{-1})^3$ is the inverse of $A^3$, you'll need to show that **both** products $(A^{-1})^3 \cdot A^3$ and $A^3 \cdot (A^{-1})^3$ are equal to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Can you explain what u mean by $A^3$ = $AAA$ and how would that work with the inverse

Comment: $AAA$ means $A$ multiplied by $A$ and then the result multiplied by $A$.

Comment: @ZeroInf, see the first two sentences of Dovah-king's answer.  It's just exponent notation.  Just like how $2^3 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$, the notation $A^3$ means $A \cdot A \cdot A$ (or just $AAA$ if we want to write even less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A^3$ is, in fact (a bit obvious), $A \times A \times A$. Do the multiplication. For b), $(A^{-1})^3$ is $A^{-1} \times A^{-1} \times A^{-1} $, do the multiplication.
Since $(A^x)^y = A^{xy}$, onde could just state that $A^{-3} = (A^{-1})^{3} = (A^3)^{-1}$, but, since the exercise wants you to show this via the results, just show that $(A^{-1})^{3}$ and $(A^3)^{-1}$ are both equal to $I_{2\times2}$.

Comment: Re: your last sentence, don't show that $(A^{-1})^3$ and $(A^{3})^{-1}$ are both equal to $I_{2 \times 2}$.  They're not and that wouldn't prove the desired result anyway.  The goal is to show that $(A^{-1})^3 \cdot A^3$ and $A^3 \cdot (A^{-1})^3$ are both equal to $I_{2 \times 2}$.  This would show that $(A^3)^{-1}$ (the inverse of $A^3$) is equal to $(A^{-1})^3$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Realized it now. Thanks.